# Determine location of laptop based on WiFi

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, geolocation, location

Say, I want to determine the location of the local machine 192.168.1.2 connected on my network. I want to find the "relative"/"absolute" ( any would do, relative is better though) of the laptop.

Is there a way to do it? WiFi based location searching (the most common answer that popped up when I searched for this) is based on position triangulation which means, the code I will run will tell me my location and not of any IP I want to search for.

Can Traceroute be used somehow? I mean, it does give me the average RTT. can I somehow use that to find the location?

I am trying to do this in Python (anyone knows of any APIs?) and no this is not a school homework ( anyhow, I am just asking for ideas).

EDIT: I want to do this over a SINGLE network only, the one I am connected to. ( if that wasn't clear). I don't want to probe into other networks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an external service, e.g. from Google.

Have a look at http://samy.pl/androidmap/ - when feeding the MAC address / BSSID of a nearby wireless LAN access point, it is likely to give you a pretty exact location (for my home's wireless lan it even has the correct address + house number).

However, finding the actual location in the house (if that's what you want), you are pretty much out of luck. You'd need to test the signal strength from multiple locations and then calculate the location - however, walls etc. would make this even harder.

Comment: Yes, the house thingy is what I'm looking for. It might not be an exact location. An approximate "relative" position would work. I don't want dwell into making the database by taking survey of signal strength. That's why the question asking for an alternative

Comment: Sadly, the [*androidmap* app](http://samy.pl/androidmap/) has been blocked by Google :(